# Python - mechanize - How to know if it works?

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to signup in one form. But how I know if it works, or what errors the form is giving (like password to short)

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.gutefrage.net/nutzer_hinzufuegen")
br.select_form(name = "regForm")

br.form['fRegister[nickname]'] = 'Username'
br.form['fRegister[email]'] = 'email@email.com'
br.form['fRegister[password]'] = 'password'
for i in range(0, len(br.find_control(name="fRegister[accept]").items)):
br.find_control(name="fRegister[accept]").items[i].selected =True

req = br.submit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req = br.submit()` returns the html page to `req` once submitted. See the output using `print req` or `print req.read()`. If successfully logged in, the req will contain the logged in page